# Arrange an array recursively

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I'm trying to arrange an array in levels. This is my array:

```
Array
  (
    [0] => Array(
      [0] => Array(
        [id] => 971249312[name] => Wolverine
      )

      [children] => Array(
        [0] => Array(
          [0] => Array(
            [id] => 735327624[name] => Ciclop
          )

          [children] => Array()
        )
      )
    )

    [1] => Array(
      [0] => Array(
        [id] => 1926833684[name] => Gambit
      )
      [children] => Array()
    )

    [2] => Array(
      [0] => Array(
        [id] => 51194629[name] => Quicksilver
      )
      [children] => Array()
    )
  )
```

See that the first position of array has 3 elements - this must be the level 0. The first position of these elements must be the level 1. The children of these elements are the next level and so on.
I can´t figure out how to arrange it.

the expected output:

```
Array
(
    ["level_1"] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 971249312
                    [name] => Wolverine
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1926833684
                    [name] => Gambit
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 51194629
                    [name] => Quicksilver
                )

        )

    ["level_2"] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 735327624
                    [name] => Ciclop
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: Can u figure out the desired output what you required

Comment: Please post your expected output

Comment: @KARTHISRV I edited the post with the expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another recursive tree walk.

I scan the tree 'depth first' so I need to keep track of the current 'level'.

[Demonstration at eval.in](https://eval.in/729627)

*Tree scan routine:*

```
/**
 * Recursive scan of the tree
 * 
 * @node   array    Current Node to be processed
 * @level  integer  Current depth of the tree
 * output  array    reference to where to store the details
 *   
 * @return void
 */   
function scanNode($node, $level, &$output)
{
    $outLevelIdx = 'level_'. $level; 

    foreach ($node as $idx => $info) {

        $parent = current($info); 

        $output[$outLevelIdx][] = array('id' => $parent['id'], 'name' => $parent['name']);

        if (!empty($info['children'])) { // go scan the children
            scanNode($info['children'], $level + 1, $output);
        }        
    }  
}
```

*Run the scan:*

```
/*
 *  Output array in here - pass as a reference 
 */  
$output = array();

// scan the full tree
scanNode($source, 0, $output);
```

*Sample output:*

```
output
Array
(
    [level_0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 971249312
                    [name] => Wolverine
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1926833684
                    [name] => Gambit
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 51194629
                    [name] => Quicksilver
                )
        )

    [level_1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 735327624
                    [name] => Ciclop
                )
        )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

If your desired output is

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 971249312
            [name] => Wolverine
            [children] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 971249312
            [name] => Wolverine
            [children] => Array
                (
                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 971249312
            [name] => Wolverine
            [children] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

Then your code should be

```
$newArray = [];
foreach ($givenArray as $key => $value) {
    $newArray[$key]['id'] = $value[0]['id'];
    $newArray[$key]['name'] = $value[0]['name'];
    $newArray[$key]['children'] = $value['children'];
}
```

**AS per your desired output**

This function used to scan all the node and provide as per your requirment.

[OUTPUT](https://eval.in/729706)

```
$newArray = [];
myfunction($a, 0,$newArray);


function myfunction($loop, $level, &$newArray) {
    $index = "level_".$level;
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($loop as $key => $value) {
        foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1) {
            if($key1 !== 'children'){
                $newArray[$index][$i] = ['id' => $value1['id'], 'name' => $value1['name']];
                $i++;
            }
        }
        if (isset($value['children']) && !empty($value['children'])) { 
            myfunction($value['children'], $level + 1, $newArray);
        }
    }

}
print_r($newArray);exit;
```

Comment: @RyanVincent, KARTIS SRV thanks man you are great,  work fine!